# How to get directory tenant name in Azure ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I need to use a tenant (directory tenant) name in my ARM templates (especially when creating Web Apps).
[image]
It is possible to get subscription name using `subscription().displayName` however, how can I get my associated directory tenant name?
The expressions like `[subscription().tenantId.displayName]` or `[subscription().tenantId.Name]` aren't working and also I'm unable to find any presence of this property on the web.
The way I won't hardcode it is that it can be easily changed by subscription owner or account admin that's why I'm looking for some existing variable\parameter\etc

Comment: so you need to pass it in as a parameter or read from some resource propertty

Comment: I don't want to use hardcoded objects. Could you be more precise - which resource has `tenant name` property, for example?

Comment: not a single one (to my knowledge), but you can create a resource and set one of its properties to tenant name. also, since when are parameters hardcoded? btw, you can create a fake template with only outputs tenant name and deploy it. after that you can read its output in your template. thats effectively hardcoding though

Comment: I'll try to be more convincing - as `tenant name` can't be grabbed from any internal objects in ARM model, the only way is to specify it manually. Imagine that the account admin or subscription owner\global admin changed the directory name one day - and all my code which rely on this (old) name will fail. How can I be sure to have always "fresh" directory name? How can I create a resource and set it's property to a tenant name given that the name may change in future?

Comment: you cant. there is no arm function for that.the only thing you can do is create a powershell\whatever script to get that data dynamically and pass it as a parameter. tbh, you shouldn't use tenant name anyway.

Answer (score 14):

The tenantId is now available with template functions.  Use the subscription function:  subscription().

Try the following output examples for reference:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "subscriptionOutput": {
            "value": "[subscription()]",
            "type" : "object"
        }
    }
}
```

---

For the tenant id:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "subscriptionOutput": {
            "value": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "type" : "object"
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#subscription

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this. you can only get these values back:

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}",
    "subscriptionId": "{subscription-id}",
    "tenantId": "{tenant-id}",
    "displayName": "{name-of-subscription}"
}
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#subscription

Answer (score 0):

You could run a deployment script as your first resource. Then, in powershell write the tenant name as a tag to the resource group your arm template is deploying to. Youll need to create a managed identity in the deployment too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.managedidentity/userassignedidentities?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template

```
Connect-AzAccount -identity
$TN = (Get-AzTenant).Name
$Tags += @{"TenantName"=$TN}
Set-AzResourceGroup -Name <your-resource-group-name> -Tag $Tags
```

Then in you arm template, just reference

"[resourceGroup().tags.TenantName]"